# JUnit Attachments Plugin is not working on Hudson

Tags: junit, hudson, automated-tests, integration-testing

I'm running integration tests using TestNG and Hudson combination. I'm able to generate my own customized JUnit XML files for Hudson for reporting purpose. And Hudson displays my customized report greatly. Now I want to attach test results which are of .txt files to my test class/test method. I have taken JUnit Attachments Plugin and installed it on Hudson. I generated the .txt files into the surefire-reports//*-output.txt directory as per the example mentioned in the following link: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/JUnit+Attachments+Plugin.

But JUnit Attachments Plugin is not working on Hudson. I'm unable to see the attachments in Hudson.

Any suggestions to make it work?